# How to find RPG games in my steam library?

Tags: steam

So this might sound stupid, but I've kinda lost the overview over all the games I have on steam, which now becomes a problem, since I don't know how to find games I actually want to play.

I want to find a few turn-based RPG games that are made to look like 8-bit-games, like Call of Cthulhu, Breath of Fire VII or the old Final Fantasy games. Do you have any advice on how to efficiently search my steam library for games like that?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to sort your library by tags/genre.  Though, that would be a very useful feature.

Comment: I didn't want to add this as an answer, since it's unofficial, but in case you're using Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox or Opera, you can also add [Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/). This adds several features, including the ability to search your library through genres(like RPG, Strategy, etc.) and categories(like Co-op, VR Support, etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First use your browser, not the Steam client, to log into the [Steam Store](http://store.steampowered.com). Then use this [Steam Store search](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?snr=1_237_237__12&term=#sort_by=_ASC&tags=122%2C1677%2C4004&page=1) to find all the games that are tagged with RPG, Turn-Based, and Retro. All the games that are in your library will be marked with blue boxes like in the following picture:

[image: Steam Store Screenshot]

Now in the Steam client you can set an appropriate category or categories for each of these games like Ragnagord suggested. You'll have to this manually, but you can put the Steam client and your browser side by side to make this easier. You also won't have to do all 800+ games at once.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks! Last time I tried, it wasn't possible to combine tags, but I believe they've added this feature ... I'll give it a try tonight!

Comment: Yah, the recent big update to the store changed the search interface quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative method is to use [depressurizer](https://github.com/rallion/depressurizer) for Steam. It's an open source application that reads your game library and then will set the categories as they appear in the marketplace. As the blurb says:

> Depressurizer can also autocategorize your games for you. Currently,
>   it does so based on data from that games' Steam store pages. It can
>   use genres, store categories (like "Single-Player" and "Steam Cloud")
>   or tags.

Using these tags, you can set your game library into categories and easily find the game styles you want. This does rely on marketplace genres or user suggested tags, so it's not infallible.

---

I'm not associated with the program, but have used it before several times

Answer (score 4):

You can set categories for each game (right click -> set categories...). You can set multiple categories per game. Also, searching for category names in the search bar will show all games with that category.

(I should note that i am using the newest beta version of the client, which may have new features implemented which might be unavailable in the regular client.)

Comment: However, this would require for me to manually sort 800+ games, which I am not quite fond of, as I stated in my question ;)

Comment: You would only have to do this once, though, then you never have this problem again

Comment: @Gin-San Computers can only do so much, sometimes you got to take stuff into your own hands.

Comment: Well that's none of your business, is it? :DD Sorry, just had to >///<

Answer (score 0):

[Lorenzo Stanco provides a steam library filter](http://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/). You can post your steam id and sort your library by tags.

Comment: Any ideas why this answer got downvoted?